# Unit Testing Daemon Thread's code in Java using JUnit

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I have created two classes which extends Thread and implements the run method.

```
class A extends Thread implements MyInterface {

    public void run() {
    }

    public function() {
        B b= new b();
        b.start();
    }
}

class B extends Thread implements OtherInterafce {

    MyClassC  object = new MyClassC();

    public void run() {
        for(;;) {
            object.callMethod();
            object.callMethod2();
            //Perform some operations
        }
    }
 }
```

Now I want to write unit Test for these classes, Since Class B is creating a daemon thread there is no exit condition, I am not sure how to test this part. I can create a mock of `object` but how many times that will run I am not sure, so how should I very the calls to the methods.

Comment: Class B does not _create_ a thread.  Class B _is_ a `Thread` instance, and its `run()` method will be run _in_ a thread if some other thread calls `new B().start()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to terminate your thread. There are many ways to do this, so I suggest you research the topic. One example is a volatile flag, which is examined every time your thread loops.

Once you can terminate the thread, then you can test it. There are a few options on how to do this. The easiest might be to create a thread that always executes once, then checks for a cancellation flag. I.e. a structure like:

```
public void run() {
    do {
        object.callMethod();
        object.callMethod2();
        //Perform some operations
    } while (conditionIsTrue);
}
```

In your test you can construct your thread object and immediately set the flag to `false`. Then your thread will run just once around the loop, allowing you to accurately verify interactions with your mocked object.

Answer (score 3):

Unit testing multithreading is **very** hard. Better just test the logic and not the threading. You could  extract the inner part and test it in isolation:

```
public void run() {
    for(;;) {
        performOperations(object);
    }
}

public performOperations(MyClassC object) {
    object.callMethod();
    object.callMethod2();
    //Perform some operations
}
```

Then you can create a test for `performOperations()`.